# Phabricator tasks and assignments via Zapier

Tags: webhooks, zapier, phabricator

This seems very niche but I have a working system that I would like to simply add to.

Currently, I've a command in a game I've written call a simple Zapier url. Lets say, `https://zapier.com/xxxxxxxx?name=me&message=hello%20there&location=location`.

When called, it posts the name, location, and message to a discord channel. I would like this to e extended.

What I would, ideally, need is to figure out how Zapier could create a new task in Phabricator manifest titled something like "Bug 231" with the context including name, location, and message, and put it on a projects workboard under a specific category and assign users to it.

I feel like this is possible but cannot figure out the proper syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zapier itself can perform extra actions out-of-the-box with "Multi-Step zaps". You could add an action after your Discord step to create a Phabricator task.

But, it looks like there's no Phabricator integration on Zapier. If Phabricator has a web API that allows for task creation, you can plug that into Zapier via either:

- a "Webhooks by Zapier" step that makes the request
- a "Code by Zapier" step if extra processing is needed
- a custom Zapier integration w/ Phabricator if you anticipate wanting more actions than "Create Task"

Comment: How would I, for example, send a json payload to phabricator?

Comment: All three of the above options will let you send JSON to Phabricator. They're ranked from simplest -> most complex, so I'd try "Webhooks by Zapier" to start - there's a spot for key/value entries.

Comment: Got it, thank you! I had to use python in this context as Phabricator doesn't make it easy on me. :)

Answer (score 0):

For those seeking similar, I found a way that worked for me :

1- I used https://www.freeformatter.com/json-formatter.html#ad-output to help me with Phabricator's interesting requirements.

2- I went in to conduit / maniphest.edit and used this JSON in the first field to get my desired curl output : [{"type":"title", "value":"test title"},{"type":"description", "value":"This is the description."},{"type":"projects.set", "value":["PHID-PROJ-4dufje6oug3liomahstg"]}]

3. I took the curl it gave me and put it in here : https://curl.trillworks.com to turn it in to python.
4. I put the python in to the Zapier python module, replacing text in several places with the variables that Zapier provides.